# Exporting from cinema-4d to unity5

Tags: 3d, unity-game-engine, fbx, cinema-4d

I am having a huge challenge in converting a particular model from c4d to unity. I do not have cinema 4d r11 or r18 and I have tried all other alternatives possible but no luck. I would appreciate if someone who has cinema 4d r16 or r18 to assist me in exporting the model to unity from c4d.

Comment: I haven't used C4D not Unity in a long time, but I remember years ago it was a matter of simply dragging the .c4d file straight into the unity project

Answer (score 0):

if you have animated model(from maximo) when you export it as FBX from cinema 4d it changes all the ":" in the name to "_"! "myrig:Bone" became "myrig_Bone". Unity will fail to match it to mode!

- Import the T-Pose model from Mixamo as "FBX for Unity"
- Import it in Cinema4D and export it as FBX again to change all the bone names with a "_"

For .c4d files just drag and drop it to unity asset folder(project).